# Enabling “elide” property in the QML Text element, but in Right-to-left User Interfaces

Tags: qt, text, qml

I understand that the "width" property must be set implicitly for elide to work. However, I have a Text element in a Layout. I would like to truncate the text when it gets too long. How can I use elide in a Text type when Right-to-Left user interface is enabled (FYI, I am using `LayoutMirroring.enabled : True` property)?

Moreover, with this, I see an alignment issue when I set width property to some value implicitly.
The issue is, for Arabic language, it works properly but sometimes there are English texts which has no translation in Arabic and needs to behave same as Arabic(which means they must align from the Right), but still English text are aligning from Left.

If I remove width property everything works fine but elide doesn't work....

```
Text {
        id: textId

        text: "Toooooooooooooooooooooooooo Looooooooooooooooonggggg"

        anchors.left: rootId.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 148
        anchors.baseline: headerId.baseline
        anchors.baselineOffset: 40

        width: 360
        elide: Text.ElideRight

        LayoutMirroring.enabled: ifArabicSelected ? True : False

        opacity: visible ? 1 : 0

        color: Colors.text_color_light

        Behavior on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: Durations.anim_menuDuration }}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text elide doesn't work without explicitly set `width`. You already know about the paragraph https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#elide-prop :

> Set this property to elide parts of the text fit to the Text item's width. The text will only elide if an explicit width has been set.

So, when using inside layout why do you use `anchors`? This doesn't seem correct way for positioning `Item` inside layout. You should use the attached property `Layout` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#preferredWidth-attached-prop and also align an `Item` using this property https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#alignment-attached-prop . Also, why not bind `width` property to parent size? it's still might work. Text elide will be enabled for any direction, but with `width` explicitly specified (or at least `Layout.width`).

Second thing, you mirrored your layout. You should also change the elide direction. See my example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Text {
        property bool ifArabicSelected: true
        id: textId
        text: "Toooooooooooooooooooooooooo Looooooooooooooooonggggg"
        anchors.left: root.left
        anchors.right: root.right
        width: parent.width
        height: 32
        anchors.baselineOffset: 40
        elide: Text.ElideLeft
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
        opacity: visible ? 1 : 0
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

Is this something you're trying to achieve? You need to specify conditional binding to `elide` propty too. This example just shows elide from the other direction, which I think you need in your example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. It really helped me and everything just works fine for me now. I have learnt two things from the solution. First, if you are using width property in mirror layout you have to mandatory use horizontalAlignment property. Second, for Arabic or RTL languages, elide:Text.ElideRight should be used, not elide:Text.ElideLeft, no matter LayoutMirroring is enabled or not.

Comment: Did you put "anchors.right: root.left" on purpose or is it a mistake?

Comment: Probably it was a mistake. I changed the original post. Anchors don't have anything in common with Text direction

Answer (score 0):

> Second, for Arabic or RTL languages, elide:Text.ElideRight should be used, not elide:Text.ElideLeft, no matter LayoutMirroring is enabled or not.

I think some of the confusion with "elide" property comes from the fact that it is badly named API in my opinion. If it was named ElideStart / ElideEnd, it would make a lot more sense. The second reason is that docs for Qt Quick's Text item could be better. If you look at QFontMetrics class docs:

> "The elide mark follows the layoutdirection. For example, it will be
> on the right side of the text for right-to-left layouts if the mode is
> Qt::ElideLeft, and on the left side of the text if the mode is
> Qt::ElideRight."

Still confused? Yeah, me too.. because as far as I can tell "layoutdirection" is not read anywhere by the implementation, so If we ignore "The elide mark follows the layoutdirection." part from the docs and read it as "elide char placement depends on text's directionality". Text directionality is determined by Unicode defined rules. For example:

```
"hello word" - directionality is left-to-right (LTR) 
"الخطوة" - directionality is right-to-left (RTL)
```

ElideRight / ElideEnd would mean:

```
"hello ..."
"...الخطوة" // because in RTL text that is **the end** of the text.
```

ElideLeft / ElideStart would mean:

```
"... hello"
"الخطوة..." // because in RTL text this is **the start** if the text.
```

Now when you think about directionality (not "layoutdirection") and about text start/end (not ElideLeft/ElideRight), then it makes sense to me at least.

Also as you have already discovered "LayoutMirroring.enabled" has no effect on where the elide char appears, which now makes sense, because layout is irrelevant here, but text directionality is what matters.

> for Arabic or RTL languages, elide:Text.ElideRight should be used

It really depends where you want the "..." to appear. If at the end of the arabic text, then yes, use Text.ElideRight.

So the conclusion is that when you go to Arabic speaking country, you do not need to invert left with right, when giving directions to the taxi driver.

If you agree with me that start/end is more clear for brain to process, this is what you can do in your qml:

```
readonly property int text_ElideStart: Text.ElideLeft
readonly property int text_ElideEnd: Text.ElideRight

Text {
    width: 40
    elide: text_ElideEnd
    text: "الخطوة"
}
```